# How to fill 3d array with contents from two other 3d arrays with unequal first and second dimensions

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have two 3d arrays of data from two separate vendors.
For both arrays, the dimesions are:

Dimension 1: dates

Dimension 2: instruments (different futures deliveries)

Dimension 3: six instrument attributes (open, high, low, close, volume, openInterest)

For each 3D array, I have two variables for the dates and instruments (`A1Times` and `A1Inst` in my code, for example).

However, the dates and instruments are not the same in the two arrays, although there is significant overlap. Some dates and/or instruments may exist in `Array1` and not `Array2` or vice versa.

I am trying to create `Array3`, a third 3d array of data where the first dimension is the union of dates from both sources, second dimension is union of available instruments, and third dimension is again the six instrument attributes.

If at all possible, I want to populate Array3 from Array2. Only if there's nothing in Array2 do I want to populate from Array1.
So for a given instrument and date, if data exists in Array1 and Array2, I want to populate Array3 from Array2.

I have tried a solution converting slices of the arrays to timetables, using retime to get the slices to the same time length, and copying over the data to the third array. This is slow and I think there has to be a better way. If someone can show me a vectorized way to do this I would appreciate it.

```
Array1 = randn(4,5,6); % time x instrument x attribute
A1Times = datetime([today-3:today]', 'ConvertFrom','datenum'); % times of first dimension of Array1
A1Inst = [3 4 5 6 7]';    % instruments of second dimension of Array1
Array1(round(1 + (numel(Array1)-1).*rand(round(numel(Array1)/5),1))) = NaN; % put a few random NaNs in the array

Array2 = randn(6,8,6);
A2Times = datetime([today-2:today+3]','ConvertFrom','datenum'); % times of first dimension of Array2
A2Inst = [1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10]'; % instruments of second dimension of Array2
Array2(round(1 + (numel(Array2)-1).*rand(round(numel(Array2)/5),1))) = NaN; % put a few random NaNs in the array

% third dimension will always be the same for both matrices

dateUnion = union(A1Times,A2Times);
instrumentUnion = union(A1Inst,A2Inst);

% Initialize A3:

Array3 = NaN(numel(dateUnion),numel(instrumentUnion),6);

% what I want to do:
% if data exists for both Array1 and Array2, populate Array3 with data from Array1
% if data doesn't exist for Array1 and does exist for Array2, populate Array3 from Array2


%% clumsy retime solution, with two for loops

A1varnames = matlab.lang.makeValidName(cellstr([repmat('Array1Instrument',numel(A1Inst),1) num2str(A1Inst)]));
A2varnames = matlab.lang.makeValidName(cellstr([repmat('Array2Instrument',numel(A2Inst),1) num2str(A2Inst)]));

for ij = 1:6 % looping through third dimension

    A1layer = array2timetable(Array1(:,:,ij),'RowTimes',A1Times);
    A1layer.Properties.VariableNames = A1varnames;

    A2layer = array2timetable(Array2(:,:,ij),'RowTimes',A2Times);
    A2layer.Properties.VariableNames = A2varnames;

    A1layer = retime(A1layer,dateUnion);
    A2layer = retime(A2layer,dateUnion);

    for ii = 1:numel(instrumentUnion)
        [~,A1loc] = ismember(instrumentUnion(ii),A1Inst);
        [~,A2loc] = ismember(instrumentUnion(ii),A2Inst);

        if (A1loc == 0)
            Array3(:,ii,ij) = A2layer{:,A2loc};
        elseif A2loc == 0
            Array3(:,ii,ij) = A1layer{:,A1loc};
        else % if instrument exists in both sources
            A1vec = A1layer{:,A1loc};
            A2vec = A2layer{:,A2loc};
            % if data exists in Array2 and Array1, choose Array2
            % if data exists in Array2 and not Array1, choose Array2
            % if data exists in Array1 and not Array2, choose Array1
            bothpopulated = ~isnan(A1vec) & ~isnan(A2vec);
            onlyA2populated = ~isnan(A2vec) & isnan(A1vec);
            onlyA1populated = isnan(A2vec) & ~isnan(A1vec);
            Array3(bothpopulated,ii,ij) = A2vec(bothpopulated);
            Array3(onlyA2populated,ii,ij) = A2vec(onlyA2populated);
            Array3(onlyA1populated,ii,ij) = A1vec(onlyA1populated);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I do not really understand your arrays. You have 3D arrays of values, and the index (in pseudo-code) `a(date, instrument, attribute)`. I guess from your example that you have separate variables for `date` and `instrument`, correct?

Now you want to combine them into a single 3D-array, correct?

Comment: That sounds correct. My problem is handling the matching of indices of two 3D arrays that aren't the same size, when I combine them to a single 3D array. I do have separate date and instrument variables for each 3D array, I should have made that clearer and will edit my question.

Comment: I guess that it happens that you have data for multiple instruments on the same date, correct? How is that represented in the variable that contains the `instrument`-index for the arrays? Would it be (again pseudocode) `dates1 = [2019/7/1 2019/7/1 2019/7/2]` and `instruments1 = [1 2 1]`?

Comment: It definitely happens that I have data for multiple instruments on the same date. But both `dates1` and `instruments1` have unique contents. They would look more like `dates1 = [20190701 20190702 20190703]` and `instruments1 = [1 2 3]`. Every row of the first dimension is a unique date; every column along the second dimension a unique instrument.

Comment: Uh, yes, I was thinking in the wrong direction. I guess that rahnema1's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to map `AxTimes` and `AxInst` to sequential integers so they can be used for multidimensional array indexing. The third output of `unique` gives those indices. After that you just need to use logical and multidimensional array indexing to assign the values. Here I simplified your example and changed `A1Times` to numbers.

```
Array1 = randn(4,5,6);
A1Times = [1 2 3 4].'
A1Inst = [3 4 5 6 7].';    
Array1(round(1 + (numel(Array1)-1).*rand(round(numel(Array1)/5),1))) = NaN;

Array2 = randn(6,8,6);
A2Times = [3 4 5 6 7 8].';
A2Inst = [1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10].'; 
Array2(round(1 + (numel(Array2)-1).*rand(round(numel(Array2)/5),1))) = NaN;

[ut,~,iut] = unique([A1Times; A2Times]);
[ui,~,iui] = unique([A1Inst; A2Inst]);


Array3 = NaN(numel(ut), numel(ui), 6);

Array3(iut(numel(A1Times)+1:end), iui(numel(A1Inst)+1:end), :) = Array2;

idx3 = false(size(Array3));
idx3(iut(1:numel(A1Times)), iui(1:numel(A1Inst)), :) = true;
idx3 = idx3 & isnan(Array3);

idx1 = idx3(iut(1:numel(A1Times)), iui(1:numel(A1Inst)), :);

Array3(idx3) = Array1(idx1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm only seeing data from Array2 (none from Array1) in your Array3, but I'm working through your answer to figure out exactly how it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, Glad to help!